# SharePoint 2010 - Powershell, how do I move a link from discussions to lists?

Tags: 2010, powershell

I cannot seem to find a way or grasp a method to take one link from the discussion bar on quicklaunch and move it to the lists section on quicklaunch. Anyone have any suggestions/help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the below linked article could tell you how to do it and much more.  Basically, you would create a new link then delete the old.

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/working-with-quick-launch-from.html

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yourServer/sites/yourSite
$quicklaunch = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$navnode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Get help!", "/sites/helpsite", $false)
$heading = $quicklaunch | where {$_.title -eq "Lists"}
$heading.Children.AddAsLast($navnode)
$heading | Select -ExpandProperty Children | where { $_.Title -eq "Tasks" } | ForEach { $_.Delete() }
```

*The above code was copied and pasted from the source link for posterity and does not reflect actual code that should be used in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm, now if I can just figure out why it goes away after I delete a different node I will be golden.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answered your question, could you please mark as answer.